# awk print the field associated with specific last record

Tags: shell, awk

I have a question about awk print.

here's my brief data file format

```
$cat file.dat

1 3 5 7 9
2 3 7 5 9
7 8 2 4 6
0 2 0 3 4
```

I want to print the column using "awk"
If the last record value of the n-th column is greater than 0,

like this form

```
$cat file2.dat

3 7 9
3 5 9 
8 4 6
2 3 4
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please do explain your logic of getting your expected output in your question. Also please do add efforts in your question too.

Comment: You should show a realistic input/output pair. Since the input contains literally `$n` and you refer to that as being a number, the sample input is not representative of the true input.

Comment: If you are trying to ask "how can I remove all columns which contain 0 on the last row" that should be straightforward with a two-pass approach; read the file but ignore all lines except the last, extract the indices of the fields with non-zeros, read the whole file again and print the fields selected by those indices.

Comment: `tac file | awk | tac` would work also.

Comment: I'm sorry about my not enough logic and explanation. My data file has over 100 columns and 100003 lines and the last record of each column is over 2000.so I explained my question in simple form.

Comment: and I'm a beginner at Linux. Please understand with a generous heart.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v col=3 '$NF > 0 { print $col }' file
```

Specify the column to print using the variable col. Then when the last column entry ($NF) is greater than 0, print the entry of the column specified by col ($col)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Can I apply all columns at the same time instead of each column separately? your answer is only work in $3 column. (sorry. I'm a total novice to Linux.)

Comment: Yeah. Just "print" instead of "print $col" This will print the whole line.

Comment: Are you saying that I just need to change 'print $ col' to 'print'?  but is not working.